# How do I disable 'Transfer-Encoding: chunked' encoding in Varnish?

Tags: http, varnish, chunked, transfer-encoding, http-content-length

Using [Varnish 4](https://www.varnish-cache.org/content/varnish-cache-400), I have a set of backends that're responding with a valid `Content-Length` header and no `Transfer-Encoding` header.

On the first hit from a client, rather than responding to the client with those headers, Varnish is dropping the `Content-Length` header and adding `Transfer-Encoding: chunked` to the response.  (Interestingly, the payload doesn't appear to have any chunks in it - it's one contiguous payload).

This causes serious problems for clients like Flash video players that are trying to do segment-size, bandwidth, etc analysis based on the `Content-Length` header.  Their analysis fails, and they can't do things like multi-bitrate streaming, etc.

I've tried a number of semi-obvious things like:

- `beresp.do_stream = true`
- `beresp.do_gzip = false`
- `unset req.http.Accept-Encoding`

Sample backend response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: public, max-age=600
Content-Type: video/mp4
Date: Tue, 13 May 2014 19:44:35 GMT
Server: Apache
Content-Length: 796618
Connection: keep-alive
```

Sample varnish response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Server: Apache
Cache-Control: public, max-age=600
Content-Type: video/mp4
Date: Tue, 13 May 2014 23:10:06 GMT
X-Varnish: 2
Age: 0
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Accept-Ranges: bytes
```

Subsequent loads of the object *do* including the `Content-Length` header, just not the first load into cache.

VCL: https://gist.github.com/onethumb/e64a405cc579909cace1

varnishlog output: https://gist.github.com/onethumb/e66a2bc4727a3a5340b6

Varnish Trac: https://www.varnish-cache.org/trac/ticket/1506

Comment: have the problem too, wait for update without bypassing the streamer.

Answer (score 6):

For the time being, `do_stream = false` will do what you want.

Avoiding chunked encoding for the case where the backend sends unchunked is a possible future improvement to Varnish.

Example:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
        if(beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "video") {
                set beresp.do_stream = false;
                set beresp.do_gzip = false;
                //set resp.http.Content-Length = beresp.http.Content-Length;
        }
        if(beresp.http.Edge-Control == "no-store") {
                set beresp.uncacheable = true;
                set beresp.ttl = 60s;
                set beresp.http.Smug-Cacheable = "No";
                return(deliver);
        }
}
```

Comment: Deleted my answer, yours is better

Comment: I tried `set beresp.do_stream=false` already, with the same result. :(

Comment: I should clarify, now that I've done more testing.  `beresp.do_stream=false` improves the success rate, but errors still occur.  I'm clocking at least a 10% rate of this problem even with `do_stream` set to `false`

Comment: @BrandonWamboldt Your answer is great as it delicately points out the relative code which could be helpful for newcomers (They might lack the required reputation to view the answer). Thanks and +1 Here anyway =)

Comment: @DonMacAskill Just curious, try enabling ESI per my answer and see if that works. I get 100% success rate.

Comment: I think beresp.do_stream only affects requests until the object is cached. Future responses are always chunked unless the origin server included a Content-Length header (ie. didn't chunk the response).

Answer (score 3):

So the solution is not at all intuitive, but you must enable esi processing:

```
sub vcl_backend_response {
        set beresp.do_esi = true;

        if(beresp.http.Content-Type ~ "video") {
                set beresp.do_stream = true;
                set beresp.do_gzip = false;
                //set resp.http.Content-Length = beresp.http.Content-Length;
        }
        if(beresp.http.Edge-Control == "no-store") {
                set beresp.uncacheable = true;
                set beresp.ttl = 60s;
                set beresp.http.Smug-Cacheable = "No";
                return(deliver);
        }
}
```

So I discovered this by browsing [the source code](https://github.com/varnish/Varnish-Cache/blob/2c2eb9bcf45f75676f91eb6de2a4febd680db716/bin/varnishd/cache/cache_http1_deliver.c#L240).

In particular, Varnish does this:

```
if (!req->disable_esi && req->obj->esidata != NULL) {
    /* In ESI mode, we can't know the aggregate length */
    req->res_mode &= ~RES_LEN;
    req->res_mode |= RES_ESI;
}
```

The above code sets the `res_mode` flag.

A little while later:

```
if (!(req->res_mode & (RES_LEN|RES_CHUNKED|RES_EOF))) {
    /* We havn't chosen yet, do so */
    if (!req->wantbody) {
        /* Nothing */
    } else if (req->http->protover >= 11) {
        req->res_mode |= RES_CHUNKED;
    } else {
        req->res_mode |= RES_EOF;
        req->doclose = SC_TX_EOF;
    }
}
```

This sets the `res_mode` flag to `RES_CHUNKED` if the HTTP protocol is `HTTP/1.1` or higher (which it is in your example) **and the res_mode flag isn't set**. Now even later:

```
if (req->res_mode & RES_CHUNKED)
    http_SetHeader(req->resp, "Transfer-Encoding: chunked");
```

Varnish sends the chuncked transfer encoding if the `RES_CHUNKED` flag is set.

The **only** way I see to effectively disable this is by enabling ESI mode. It gets disabled in a few other ways, but those aren't practical (e.g. for HTTP HEAD requests or pages with a 304 status code).

Comment: `if (!(req->res_mode & (RES_LEN|RES_CHUNKED|RES_EOF)))` checks whether `res_mode` flag has either `RES_LEN`, `RES_CHUNKED` or `RES_EOF` set, but the code inside `if (!req->disable_esi && req->obj->esidata != NULL)` only unset `RES_LEN` and set `RES_ESI`. And according to [here](https://github.com/varnish/Varnish-Cache/blob/2c2eb9bcf45f75676f91eb6de2a4febd680db716/bin/varnishd/cache/cache_http1_deliver.c#L291), the `Content-Length` will be stripped out eventually?

Answer (score 1):

Upgraded from varnish 4.0 to 5.2 and now this works correctly also for the 1st request.